# How to estimate sampled area when using reduceRegion on points instead of a polygon?

Tags: google-earth-engine

When using `reduceRegion` with a point collection instead of a polygon or other geometry, I want to understand how the total sampled area is calculated, especially since the methodology impacts the outcome significantly. With a polygon, the sampled area is straightforward—it's the polygon's area. However, with points, it's not as clear whether the sampling process involves: A) directly sampling the point, B) creating a square buffer around the point with an area based on the scale (scale x scale or a²), or C) using a circular buffer calculated by scale^2pi (πr²), where the scale acts as the radius.

In the example I am providing, the difference in sampled area between a square and circular sampling method is substantial.

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/458e1ee950c77843dc40404e6c7536f9

```
// Load any image
var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1')
  .first()
  .select('NDVI')
  .clip(geometry);
// Create random point collection
var nPoints = ee.Number(50);
var points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: geometry,
  points: nPoints
});
// Define scale
var scale = ee.Number(250);

// Reduce using polygon geometry
var reducedNdviPolygon = ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: scale,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
}).getNumber('NDVI').floor();
print('reducedNdviPolygon: ',reducedNdviPolygon);
// Calculate sampled area
var polygonArea = geometry.area(ee.ErrorMargin(10));
print('Sampled area for reducedNdviPolygon: ',polygonArea.format('%,.0f'),'sq meters');

// Reduce using points geometry
var reducedNdviPoints = ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: points,
  scale: scale,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
}).getNumber('NDVI').floor();
print('reducedNdviPoints: ',reducedNdviPoints);
// Calculate sampled area
var pointsAreaSquareSampling = nPoints.multiply(scale.multiply(scale));
print('Sampled area for reducedNdviPoints if square sample: ',pointsAreaSquareSampling.format('%,.0f'),'sq meters');
var pointsAreaCircularSampling = nPoints.multiply(scale.multiply(scale).multiply(Math.PI));
print('Sampled area for reducedNdviPoints if circle sample: ',pointsAreaCircularSampling.format('%,.0f'),'sq meters');


Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(points,{},'Points');
```